# How to use capture group as start of expression in regex?

Tags: java, regex

The task at hand: I am trying to prepare for printing a specific list of automatically generated ids. They are of the format aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff-gg... every tuple is selectable by [a-zA-Z0-9]+ (of indeterminate length), the delimiters are [-] (max one).

There are anywhere between one and nine tuples in every id. If the id is 3 tuples or less, I would return one group. If the id is more than 3 tuples (4+) then I would return two groups, the first one being composed of 3 tuples, and the second one of the rest.

Only one string would be treated at a time. Here is the test set:

```
 one1
 one1-two2
 one1-two2-three3
 one1-two2-three3-4a
 one1-two2-three3-4a-5a
 one1-two2-three3-4a-5a-6a
 one1-two2-three3-4a-5a-6a-7a
```

Concretely that would mean:

```
 one1 -> {"one1"}
 one1-two2 -> {"one1-two2"}
 one1-two2-three3 -> {"one1-two2-three3"}
 one1-two2-three3-4a -> {"one1-two2-three3", "4a"}
 one1-two2-three3-4a-5a -> {"one1-two2-three3", "4a-5a"}
 one1-two2-three3-4a-5a-6a -> {"one1-two2-three3", "4a-5a-6a"}
 one1-two2-three3-4a-5a-6a-7a -> {"one1-two2-three3", "4a-5a-6a-7a"}
```

Work done up until now (this always properly selects the first group)

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[-][a-zA-Z0-9]+$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[-][a-zA-Z0-9]+[-][a-zA-Z0-9]+$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[-][a-zA-Z0-9]+[-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

What I am trying to achieve: start at the end of the capture group, check if it is not the end of the line, start reading after the first '-' char following that point, match until the end of the line.

Additional information : I am using Java's native regex engine.

Comment: One question : why would you need regex to perform this task as Java can provide you an easy solution?

Comment: I oversimplified my setup, this is a closed system, where I can insert a query and regex to treat the result (usually one String). It really needs to be done by regex. Result can be a one-value array - used as title, or a two-value array - used as title and subtitle.

Comment: Try [`(?m)^(\w+(?:-\w+){0,2})(?:-(\w+(?:-\w+)*))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/LBjUiY/1). Enabling mutiline flag provides you a way to treat each line individually. First capturing group contains 3 tuples at last. Second contains whatever comes after.

Comment: Genius. Now... how do I give you an upvote for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to over-complicate things to get around the problem:

```
(?m)^(\w+(?:-\w+){0,2})(?:-(\w+(?:-\w+)*))?$
```

`(?m)` enables multiline flag which makes `^` and `$` anchors to match beginning and end of each line respectively. A match starts with matching word characters `\w+` then up to two more of `-\w+` patterns which builds first capturing group information.

Second capturing group contains whatever comes after. If you are sure about formatting you could do this too:

```
(?m)^(\w+(?:-\w+){0,2})(.+)?$
```

Test it on [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/LBjUiY/1)

Comment: You don't need `(?m)`, `^`, and `$` when *"only one string would be treated at a time"* and using `matches()`. Also, `\w+` will incorrectly accept underscores in a tuple (*"tuple is selectable by `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`"*).

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure what OP means by *one string would be treated at a time* so I enabled `m`. In both cases, whether they are separate lines or a separate input string, this regex works. And I'm not sure if they are validating input line while capturing desired parts, hence my second recommended regex.

Comment: for my particular use '_' would never occur - so /\w+/ works just fine

also, the second regex captures the initial '-' of the second group so I wound up using `(?m)^(\w+(?:-\w+){0,2})(?:-(.+))?$`

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match only valid strings, and returns 2 capture groups:

`([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,2})(?:-([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*))?`

*Explanation*

```
(                            Start capture of group 1:
  [a-zA-Z0-9]+                 Match first tuple of group 1
  (?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,2}       Match 0-2 delimiter+tuple pairs for a total of 1-3 tuples
)                            End capture of group 1
(?:                          Optional:
  -                            Match delimiter initiating group 2
  (                            Start capture of group 2:
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+                 Match first tuple of group 2
    (?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*           Match 0+ delimiter+tuple pairs for a total of 1+ tuples
  )                            End capture of group 2
)?                           End optional
```

*Demo*

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    test("one1",
         "one1-two2",
         "one1-two2-three3",
         "one1-two2-three3-4a",
         "one1-two2-three3-4a-5a",
         "one1-two2-three3-4a-5a-6a",
         "one1-two2-three3-4a-5a-6a-7a",
         "one1-two2-three3-4a-5a-6a-7a-8a",
         "one1_two2"); // fail: invalid character
}

private static void test(String... values) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,2})(?:-([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,3}))?");
    for (String value : values) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
        if (! m.matches())
            System.out.printf("%s -> NO MATCH%n", value);
        else if (m.start(2) == -1) // capture group 2 not found
            System.out.printf("%s -> {\"%s\"}%n", value, m.group(1));
        else
            System.out.printf("%s -> {\"%s\", \"%s\"}%n", value, m.group(1), m.group(2));
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
one1 -> {"one1"}
one1-two2 -> {"one1-two2"}
one1-two2-three3 -> {"one1-two2-three3"}
one1-two2-three3-4a -> {"one1-two2-three3", "4a"}
one1-two2-three3-4a-5a -> {"one1-two2-three3", "4a-5a"}
one1-two2-three3-4a-5a-6a -> {"one1-two2-three3", "4a-5a-6a"}
one1-two2-three3-4a-5a-6a-7a -> {"one1-two2-three3", "4a-5a-6a-7a"}
one1-two2-three3-4a-5a-6a-7a-8a -> {"one1-two2-three3", "4a-5a-6a-7a-8a"}
one1_two2 -> NO MATCH
```

Comment: Why did you limit the number of tuples in second capturing group? *If the id is more than 3 tuples (4+) then I would return two groups, the first one being composed of 3 tuples, and the second one **of the rest**.*

Comment: @revo Somehow I read max 7 tuples, but that was just the examples. Fixed!

Comment: @revo Not a copy. For one, I didn't see your post until after I posted, and I show code and explanation, don't match invalid inputs, and don't use unnecessary regex patterns.